# Почему запрос SELECT возвращает число?

Tags: php, mysql, yii

Использую `Yii` для запроса:

```
return Yii::app()->db
            ->createCommand('SELECT `fio` FROM `users` WHERE `ID` = "12"')
            ->execute();
```

А он вместо имени возвращает единицу, то есть количество строк. Пробовал разные варианты - всегда возвращает `count(fio)`.

Comment: Все, разобрался, надо было вместо `execute()` использовать `queryRow()` или `queryAll()`. Всем спасибо:)

Answer (score 3):

Справка по yii говорит, что execute возвращает количество результатов (integer). 
Подробнее по [ссылке](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand#execute-detail)

Answer (score 2):

Вам не **execute()** нужен. Он всего лишь просто отправляет запрос, и все.

Вернет только первый ряд **queryRow()**

Для получения и обработки одного ряда **query()**

Для получения всех рядов **queryAll()**

Для получения столбца **queryColumn()**

Для получения первого значение в первом столбце **queryScalar()**